# Error when accessing array populated during viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a bunch of sliders in my xib file that I am referencing in my header file like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *slider1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *slider2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *slider3;
```

Then I declare my NSArray like so in header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *sliders;
```

Now in my implementation I populate the array with sliders during viewDidLoad handler

```
sliders = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:slider1, slider2, slider3, nil];
```

The properties have been synthesize of course.
It all works well so far. With breakpoints I can see that the array has been populated correctly and I get sliders value using NSLog.

The problem is when I handle a button submit event, that array seems to be empty
This line generates execution abort error:

```
id obj = [sliders objectAtIndex:0];
```

Please can anyone help point out where I have gone wrong? Is this the correct way to work with a collection of sliders or any controls for that matter? I would like to iterate through them, ideally with a dictionary so that I can refer to them with string keys but I'd settle for simple array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
sliders = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:slider1, slider2, slider3, nil];
```

With

```
self.sliders = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:slider1, slider2, slider3, nil];
```

By accessing the ivar directly you are circumventing the memory management of the property, so your array is being released after you have set it up. You then get a crash because you are messaging a released object.

Comment: 'self.' prefix solved my errors. didn't know that is not the same as using 'sliders' on its own. All 3 answers here mentioned it but I can only mark one correct answer unfortunately. Thanks all for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Can you replace:

```
   id obj = [sliders objectAtIndex:0];
```

with

```
  UISlider *obj = [sliders objectAtIndex:0];
```

also try calling

```
  self.sliders //instead of just sliders
```

and see if it still crashes
also try to make a condition if array is non-zero...
have you connected the outlets?
Are you over or under releasing
Are you on ARC?

Important questions...

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess without seeing the code but i would look for the following:

- can you display the array in the line before you use objectAtIndex using NSLOG
- are you using properties to assign to sliders (self.sliders) if not you may end up accessing deallocated array.
- If you are not using ARC, have you tried to use NSZombies to track the issue?